# The letters "ÆØÅ" does not transfer from python to my html file

Tags: python, html

My teacher gave me an assignment where he wanted me to change my html code by using python. Ofc I did that, but a problem came up when I had to write over the text from python to html.

```
def upload(ma,ti,on,to,fr,kos):
    with open('index.html','r') as f:
        lines=f.readlines()
        lines[9]=f'<p>Mandag: {ma[0]} til {ma[1]} kroner</p>\n'
        lines[10]=f'<p>Tirsdag: {ti[0]} til {ti[1]} kroner</p>\n'
        lines[11]=f'<p>Onsdag: {on[0]} til {on[1]} kroner</p>\n'
        lines[12]=f'<p>Torsdag: {to[0]} til {to[1]} kroner</p>\n'
        lines[13]=f'<p>Fredag: {fr[0]} til {fr[1]} kroner</p>\n'
        lines[14]=f'<p>Fredagskos: {kos[0]} til {kos[1]} kroner</p>\n'
    
    with open('index.html','w') as f:
        f.writelines(lines)
        f.close()
```

The code works as it should it transfer the text over to html, but it doesn't transfer the letters Æ, Ø or Å and it just turns into this: �

When I run the code and check the list for what the content of the list is, it showes the letters Æ, Ø and Å like they should appear, but it just doesn't write over the letters as they should.

Comment: try specifying the encoding when you write the file: `with open('index.html', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:`

Comment: Sounds like you're fucking up your encoding, and being unable to decode anything the browser displays a replacement character. Since you're getting a replacement character it looks like the page is (correctly?) interpreted as UTF-8 or something similar, and I assume the incorrectly displayed characters come from the function parameters. Where do those parameters come from?

Comment: Incidentally, the entire point of `with open(...)` is to ensure the file is closed at the end of the scope, so closing it by hand is useless.